# Combinatorics question: Number of ways to sequentially grow linear chains of $n$ balls under a condition

Tags: combinatorics

This combinatorics question is motivated by the mobile app game $[Drop7][1]$.

Although the following description of the game is not complete, it is sufficient for the question at hand:

$Drop7$ is played on a $7 \times 7$ grid of squares in which on each play the player is presented with a ball, numbered $1$ to $7$, above the grid and chooses which of the seven columns to place it.  The ball then falls to the lowest available square in the chosen column.  There may or may not be other balls in each column.  After the ball rests, the game automatically finds any vertical or horizontal straight connected line of balls.  If the length of any such a connected line is $i$ ($1 \leq i \leq 7$) and contains one or more balls numbered $i$, then those balls vanish and any balls above them fall to the lowest available square in its column.  (Gravity holds.)  In fact, the game eliminates all such balls simultaneously:  If there is a connected line of length $2$ containing any balls numbered $2$ and a different connected line of length $5$ containing any balls numbered $5$, then all those balls numbered $2$ and $5$ will vanish simultaneously.

Then the game checks again for every vertical or horizontal straight connected line of balls.  If the length of any line is $i$ contains a ball numbered $i$, then that ball vanishes.  The game iterates, always reducing balls until no more can be eliminated.  Then a new ball is presented at the top and the player chooses in which column to place it.

(In $Drop7$ the goal is to eliminate balls faster than new rows of them appear... but this is not crucial to this question.)

[In this screen shot, ignore the fact that some balls are unnumbered and in gray; that is irrelevant to the question at hand.  That is, assume all balls are numbered.  In this example, if the player places the $4$ ball in the fifth column (counting from the left), then it will fall and rest between the balls labelled $6$ and $1$.  In that case, the game notes that the second horizontal row from the bottom is of length $6$ and thus eliminates the ball numbered $6$.  Then the balls above that eliminated $6$ descend and there is *again* a horizontal line of length $6$ with a ball numbered $6$, so that ball vanishes.  As well, the original ball numbered $4$ in the now-length-$4$ column will vanish... and so on until no more balls can be eliminated.]

[image]

**Question:**

Consider an empty grid and the sequence of seven balls to be presented to the player will be $1, 2, \ldots, 7$ *in some order* (that is, in some permutation of $1, \ldots, 7$).  In this problem, the player seeks to have all the balls *existing* in the first row instantaneously before the game eliminates the balls.  That is, there must be no lines of length $i$ containing a ball numbered $i$ until all seven balls have been played.

It is clear the $1$ ball must be presented last.  Otherwise, it will be in a column of height $1$ before all seven balls have been played and will vanish.

Likewise, if the player first inserts a $3$ into a column and then a $2$ in an adjacent column, a horizontal line of length $2$ will result, and the $2$ ball vanish.

But now consider the sequence where the balls are presented in sequence $7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1$ (note that specific order!) and are placed (sequentially) in columns $1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4$.  Then at no moment before the last ball stops will a ball vanish.  Let's call that sequence of balls *admissible* and the particular ordered sequence of chosen columns a *solution* for that particular admissible sequence.

Clearly, if the columns are renumbered, flipping right-to-left, the same result occurs, so that admissible sequence of balls has at least two solutions.

- For a given number of columns $n$ (here $n = 7$), how many admissible sequences $S_n$ exist?  (Solution for small $n$, found by enumeration:  $S_1 = 1$, $S_2 = 1$, $S_3 = 2$, $S_4 = 6$.)  Prove or disprove:  $S_n = (n-1)!$
- [the harder problem]  For a given admissible sequence of balls, how many solutions exist?  Is the number of solutions the same for all admissible sequences of length $n$?
- For any admissible sequence of length $n$ and solution sequence, will the game always eliminate *all* balls after they have been played?  What is the distribution of remaining balls that can exist?
- Is there any $n$ and particular admissible sequence of length $n$ for which no solution leads to all balls eliminated after play?

Comment: Your conjecture that the number of admissible sequences is $(n-1)!$ is equivalent to the statement that every sequence ending in $1$ is admissible. Once you put $1$ in the last position, there are $(n-1)!$ ways to order the rest of the balls. For $n=3$ you have to put the first two balls on the end, so will fill the row with $312$ or $213$  Then the $3$ and $1$ are eliminated, leaving the $2$.  This answers the fourth bullet and some of the third.  Similarly in your example of $1726354$ the $1$ and $7$ are eliminated, then the $5$, then the $3$, then the $2$, but the $4$ and $6$ remain.

Answer (score 1):

For the second bullet, the number of solutions need not be the same.  If four balls are presented $4321$ the solutions are $4312$, $3412$, and their reverses.  If they are presented $2341$ the solutions are $2134, 2143,4213$ and their reverses.

For the third bullet, the game will never eliminate all the balls at the end.  Once all the balls are placed, balls $1$ and $n$ will be eliminated in the first step.  Then $n-2$ balls are left, so ball $n-1$ can never be eliminated.  For $n=4$ ball $2$ cannot be eliminated because it would have to be next to $3$ and one of them would have been eliminated during the filling, so the only final configuration is balls $2,3$ left.

Comment: Good contribution and (partial) solution (+1).